# Velocity and rates of Change

Tags: calculus

A tennis ball bounces so that its initial speed straight upwards is $b$ feet per second. Its height s in feet at time t seconds is.given by  $s = bt - 16(t^2)$

a) Find the velocity $v = ds/dt$ at time $t$. **Solved**

b) Find the time at which the height of the ball is at its maximum height. **Solved**

c) Find the maximum height. **Solved**

d) Make a graph of $v$ and directly below it a graph of $s$ as a function of time. Be sure to mark the maximum of $s$ and the beginning and end of the bounce. **Solved**

e) Suppose that when the ball bounces a second time it rises to half the height of the first bounce. Make a graph of $s$ and of $v$ of both bounces, labeling the important points. (You will have to decide how long the second bounce lasts and the initial velocity at the start of the bounce.)

f) If the ball continues to bounce, how long does it take before it stops?

Can someone help me with e) in this question? I looked at the answer but don't understand where it comes from.

Comment: Where is the expression of $s$?

Comment: Sorry I think my computer didn't paste the expression correctly. it s = bt - 16(t^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the maximum height after the first bounce in part c.  When it bounces again some energy is lost to flexure in the ball, so the upward velocity is lower than the velocity at time zero.  You are expected to find the upward launch velocity so that the height is half as high.  This will be a reduction of the launch velocity by some factor.  Each bounce reduces the launch velocity by the same factor and the height by a factor $2$.  The time for each bounce is also reduced by some factor.  For e you should make a sketch of the vertical velocity and the vertical position as a function of time based on this.  For f you should sum the geometric series of the time each bounce takes.